# How to see resumable timeout of another session in oracle?

Tags: oracle

How I see the setting of timeout about resumable of another session? I've found the function `dbms_resumable.get_timeout`, but there is no way of inform some parameters about a specified session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DBA_RESUMABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/DBA_RESUMABLE.html)

> ...
>
> TIMEOUT | NUMBER | Timeout of the resumable statement
>
> ...

Session 1:

```
SQL> select sys_context('userenv', 'sid') from dual;

SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SID')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
53

SQL> alter session enable resumable timeout 600 name 'hello world';

Session altered.
```

Session 2:

```
SQL> select session_id, timeout, name from dba_resumable;

SESSION_ID    TIMEOUT NAME
---------- ---------- ------------------------------
        53        600 hello world
```

Comment: But if there is no resumable event. Will this view still work for I to see the settings about the timeout of specified session?

Comment: @DaniloNeto See my update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [DBMS_RESUMABLE.GET_SESSION_TIMEOUT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_resuma.htm#i996838). It takes one parameter - the SID of the specified database session.